# JQuery addClass() not adding class and CSS class only applying inline

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having problems with the login/register html page of a project of mine:

-hide CSS class not applying for some reason

The first is as you can see the .hide(display:none;) isn't taking effect for some reason, that makes the login form appear right bellow the main container.

-JQuery addClass()/removeClass() not working.

The second problem is my jquery function to show the login form and hide the register form when Register is clicked isn't working,  am using addClass(.hide) and removeClass(.hide) to alternate between register and logins form on a click which I think is really god behaviour,.

Here is my code:

```js
$('#showLoginForm').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     //alert('clicked register');
     $('.auth_register_container').addClass('hide');
        $('.auth_login_container').removeClass('hide'); 
    });
```

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box; margin:0; padding:0;} 

a{text-decoration:none;}

::placeholder {color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}

.input:focus{border-color: none;-webkit-box-shadow: none; box-shadow: none; outline: none;}

.hide{display:none;}

.pointer{cursor:pointer;}

.auth_maincontainer{width:38%; height:77%; position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; z-index:999999; left:50%; background-color:white; transform:translate(-50%, -50%); top:50%; border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2); box-shadow:4px 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}

.auth_register_container{width:100%; display:flex; flex-direction:column; align-items:center; background-color:white; padding-bottom:25px; height:100%; border-radius:20px;}

.auth_login_container{width:100%; display:flex; flex-direction:column; align-items:center; background-color:white; padding-bottom:25px; height:100%; border-radius:20px;}

.auth_title{margin-bottom:25px; width:100%; height:12%; display:flex; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center; font-size:25px; color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8); font-weight:600;}

.auth_form_container{width:70%; height:45px; display:flex; position:relative;}

.auth_form_submit{width:45px; height:100%; border-left:2px solid #2A3F54; border-top:2px solid #2A3F54; border-bottom:2px solid #2A3F54; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;}

.auth_form_icon{font-size:27px; color:#2A3F54;}

.auth_form_input{border:2px solid #2A3F54; font-size:19px; color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7); width:90%; height:100%; background-color:transparent; padding:8px;}

.auth_error_alert{display:none; color:#C1392B; font-size:27px; position:absolute; top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%); left:-40px;}

.auth_error_container{width:70%; height:36px; display:flex; align-items:center; visibility:hidden;}

.fa-asterisk{color:#C1392B; font-size:6px; margin-right:6px;}

.auth_error_text{color:#C1392B; font-size:13px; font-weight:500;}

.auth_remember_container{width:70%; height:30px; display:flex; align-items:center; margin-top:auto;}

.auth_remember_input{width:13px; height:13px; margin-right:5px;}

.auth_remember_text{font-size:13px; color:#333333; font-weight:400;}

.auth_registeradv_container{width:70%; height:30px; display:flex; align-items:center; margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:3px;}

.auth_registeradv_text{font-size:15px; color:rgba(0,0,0,0.9); margin-right:3px;}

.auth_registeradv_show{margin-left:7px; font-weight:900; color:rgba(0,0,0,0.9); font-size:14px;}

.fa-sign-in{font-size:15px; color:rgba(0,0,0,0.9); margin-right:3px;}

.auth_form_buttons_container{width:70%; height:45px; display:flex; justify-content:space-between; margin-top:auto;}

.auth_form_login_button{font-size:20px; padding:0px 50px; height:100%; background-color:#4D9A3A; color:white; font-weight:500; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;}

.auth_form_reset_button{font-size:20px; padding:0px 50px; height:100%; background-color:#C1392B; color:white; font-weight:00; display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;}

.auth_pattern_container{width:100%; height:40vh; background-color:#0FBCF5; position:relative; background-color:white; background-image:url('images/back2.png'); positon:relative; background-size:contain;}

.auth_filter_color{width:100%; height:40vh; position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:0px; background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);}

.auth_color_container{width:100%; height:60vh; background-color:#0FBCF5; positon:relative;}

.auth_gradient_color{width:100%; height:60vh; position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:0px;  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="display:flex; flex-direction:column; position:relative; font-family:Open Sans;">
<div class="auth_pattern_container" style="">
   <div class="auth_filter_color" style=""></div>
</div>
<div class="auth_maincontainer" style="">
    <div class="auth_register_container" style="">  
        <h1 class="auth_title" style="">REGISTRARSE</h1>
     <div class="auth_form_container" style="">
         <div class="auth_form_submit" style="">
          <i class="auth_form_icon fa fa-user" style=""></i>
      </div>
      <input class="auth_form_input" type="text" class="input" placeholder="USUARIO" style="">
         <i class="auth_error_alert fa fa-exclamation-triangle" style="" ></i>
     </div>
     <div class="auth_error_container" style="">
         <i class="fa fa-asterisk" style=""></i>
      <span class="auth_error_text" style="">El usuario no existe</span>
     </div>
     <div class="auth_form_container" style="">
         <div class="auth_form_submit" style="">
          <i class="auth_form_icon fa fa-envelope" style=""></i>
      </div>
      <input class="auth_form_input" type="email" class="input" placeholder="CORREO" style="">
         <i class="auth_error_alert fa fa-exclamation-triangle" style="" ></i>
     </div>
     <div class="auth_error_container" style="">
         <i class="fa fa-asterisk" style="color:#C1392B; font-size:6px; margin-right:6px;"></i>
      <span class="auth_form_error_text" style="">El email no coincide</span>
     </div>
     <div class="auth_form_container" style="">
         <div class="auth_form_submit" style="">
          <i class="auth_form_icon fa fa-lock" style=""></i>
      </div>
      <input class="auth_form_input" type="password" class="input" placeholder="CONTRASEÑA" style="">
      <i class="auth_error_alert fa fa-exclamation-triangle" style="" ></i>
     </div>
     <div class="auth_error_container" style="">
         <i class="fa fa-asterisk" style=""></i>
      <span class="auth_error_text" style="">La contraseña no es valida</span>
     </div>
     <div class="auth_remember_container" style="">
     <input class="auth_remember_input" type="checkbox" checked="false" style="">
  <span class="auth_remember_text" style="">Recuerdame</span>
     </div>
     <div class="auth_registeradv_container" style="">
     <span class="auth_registeradv_text" style="">¿No tienes cuenta de usuario? </span>
  <a id="showLoginForm" class="auth_registeradv_show" style="" href=""><i class="fa fa-sign-in" style=""></i>Registrate.</a>
     </div>
     <div class="auth_form_buttons_container" style="">
     <div class="auth_form_login_button pointer" style="">INICIO</div> 
  <div class="auth_form_reset_button pointer" style="">RESET</div> 
     </div>
    </div>
 <div class="auth_login_container hide" style="">  
        <h1 class="auth_title" style="">INICIAR SESIÓN</h1>
     <div class="auth_form_container" style="">
         <div class="auth_form_submit" style="">
          <i class="auth_form_icon fa fa-user" style=""></i>
      </div>
      <input class="auth_form_input" type="text" class="input" placeholder="USUARIO" style="">
         <i class="auth_error_alert fa fa-exclamation-triangle" style="" ></i>
     </div>
     <div class="auth_error_container" style="">
         <i class="fa fa-asterisk" style=""></i>
      <span class="auth_error_text" style="">El usuario no existe</span>
     </div>
     <div class="auth_form_container" style="">
         <div class="auth_form_submit" style="">
          <i class="auth_form_icon fa fa-envelope" style=""></i>
      </div>
      <input class="auth_form_input" type="email" class="input" placeholder="CORREO" style="">
         <i class="auth_error_alert fa fa-exclamation-triangle" style="" ></i>
     </div>
     <div class="auth_error_container" style="">
         <i class="fa fa-asterisk" style="color:#C1392B; font-size:6px; margin-right:6px;"></i>
      <span class="auth_form_error_text" style="">El email no coincide</span>
     </div>
     <div class="auth_form_container" style="">
         <div class="auth_form_submit" style="">
          <i class="auth_form_icon fa fa-lock" style=""></i>
      </div>
      <input class="auth_form_input" type="password" class="input" placeholder="CONTRASEÑA" style="">
      <i class="auth_error_alert fa fa-exclamation-triangle" style="" ></i>
     </div>
     <div class="auth_error_container" style="">
         <i class="fa fa-asterisk" style=""></i>
      <span class="auth_error_text" style="">La contraseña no es valida</span>
     </div>
     <div class="auth_remember_container" style="">
     <input class="auth_remember_input" type="checkbox" checked="false" style="">
  <span class="auth_remember_text" style="">Recuerdame</span>
     </div>
     <div class="auth_registeradv_container" style="">
     <span class="auth_registeradv_text" style="">¿No tienes cuenta de usuario? </span>
  <a id="showLoginForm" class="auth_registeradv_show" style="" href=""><i class="fa fa-sign-in" style=""></i>Registrate.</a>
     </div>
     <div class="auth_form_buttons_container" style="">
     <div class="auth_form_login_button pointer" style="">INICIO</div> 
  <div class="auth_form_reset_button pointer" style="">RESET</div> 
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="auth_color_container" style=" ">
 <div class="auth_gradient_color" style=""></div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sidebar_entry_link_container").click(function(){
     $('.sidebar_entry_link_container').removeClass('active_entry');
  $(this).addClass('active_entry');
        $(this).nextAll('.sidebar_entry_dropdown_container:first').slideToggle();
    });
 
 
 
 $(".navbar_menu_toggle").click(function(){
     $('.sidebar_maincontainer').toggleClass('active_sidebar_maincontainer');
  $('.body_maincontainer').toggleClass('active_body_maincontainer');
    });

 
 
 $('#showLoginForm').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     //alert('clicked register');
     $('.auth_register_container').addClass('hide');
        $('.auth_login_container').removeClass('hide'); 
    });
 
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Why do you have multiple elements with the same ID? Switch to classes and then try again (For example `id="showLoginForm"` should be replaced with `class="showLoginForm"` and then you select that element using `.showLoginForm` instead of `#showLoginForm`)

Comment: Why are you trying to create a hide class? Why not just use $('.auth_register_container').hide()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.hide`'s `display: none` is being overridden by `.auth_login_container` and `.auth_register_container`'s `display: flex`.

jQuery's `addClass` and `removeClass` work fine in the absence of those overriding styles.

The application will work as expected if you move the `.hide` style below those other two classes' styles. e.g. https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/171674/

Another technique would be to add `!important` after the `display: none` style, so it overrides other `display` styles. I know `!important` is sometimes abused, but this seems like a reasonable use case.